# Can "observer" nodes in zookeeper respond with stale results?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, distributed-computing

This question is in reference to https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperObservers.html

> Observers are non-voting members of an ensemble which only hear the
>   results of votes, not the agreement protocol that leads up to them.
>   Other than this simple distinction, Observers function exactly the
>   same as Followers - clients may connect to them and send read and
>   write requests to them. Observers forward these requests to the Leader
>   like Followers do, but they then simply wait to hear the result of the
>   vote. Because of this, we can increase the number of Observers as much
>   as we like without harming the performance of votes.
>
> Observers have other advantages. Because they do not vote, they are
>   not a critical part of the ZooKeeper ensemble. Therefore they can
>   fail, or be disconnected from the cluster, without harming the
>   availability of the ZooKeeper service. The benefit to the user is that
>   Observers may connect over less reliable network links than Followers.
>   In fact, Observers may be used to talk to a ZooKeeper server from
>   another data center. Clients of the Observer will see fast reads, as
>   all reads are served locally, and writes result in minimal network
>   traffic as the number of messages required in the absence of the vote
>   protocol is smaller.

1) **non-voting members of an ensemble** - What do the voting members vote on?

2) **How does an update request work for observers** - When a ZK leader gets an update request, it requires a quorum of nodes to respond. Observer nodes seems like is not considered a quorum node. Does that mean an observer node lags behind the leader node for updates? If that is true, how does it ensure that observer nodes do not respond with stale data during reads?

3) **Clients of the Observer will see fast reads, as all reads are served locally, and writes result in minimal network traffic as the number of messages required in the absence of the vote protocol is smaller** - Reads from all the other nodes will also be local only because they are in-sync with the leader, no? And I did not get the part about writes.

These questions should be good to understanding zookeeper and distributed systems in general. Appreciate a good detailed answer for these. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 1) **non-voting members of an ensemble** - What do the voting members vote on?

Typical members of the ensemble (not observers) vote on success/failure of proposed changes coordinated by the leader.  There is some further discussion of the details in the paper [ZooKeeper: Wait-free coordination for Internet-scale systems](http://static.cs.brown.edu/courses/csci2270/archives/2012/papers/replication/hunt.pdf).

> 2) **How does an update request work for observers** - When a ZK leader gets an update request, it requires a quorum of nodes to respond. Observer nodes seems like is not considered a quorum node. Does that mean an observer node lags behind the leader node for updates? If that is true, how does it ensure that observer nodes do not respond with stale data during reads?

You are correct that observer nodes are not considered necessary participants in the quorum.  In general, update lag will be subject to network latency between the observer and the leader.  (Whether or not this is noticeable is subject to specific external factors, such as whether or not the observer and leader are in the same data center with a low-latency network link.)

Note that even without use of observers, there is no guarantee that every server in the ensemble is always completely up to date.  The Apache ZooKeeper documentation on [Consistency Guarantees](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperProgrammers.html#ch_zkGuarantees) contains this disclaimer:

Sometimes developers mistakenly assume one other guarantee that ZooKeeper does not in fact make. This is:

> Simultaneously Consistent Cross-Client Views ZooKeeper does not
>   guarantee that at every instance in time, two different clients will
>   have identical views of ZooKeeper data. Due to factors like network
>   delays, one client may perform an update before another client gets
>   notified of the change. Consider the scenario of two clients, A and B.
>   If client A sets the value of a znode /a from 0 to 1, then tells
>   client B to read /a, client B may read the old value of 0, depending
>   on which server it is connected to. If it is important that Client A
>   and Client B read the same value, Client B should should call the
>   sync() method from the ZooKeeper API method before it performs its
>   read.

However, clients of ZooKeeper will never appear to "go back in time" by reading stale data from a point in time prior to the data they already read.  This is accomplished by attaching a monotonically increasing transaction ID (called "zxid") to each ZooKeeper transaction.  When the ZooKeeper client interacts with a server, it compares the client's last seen zxid to the current zxid of the server.  If the server is behind the client, then it will not allow the client's next read to be processed by that server.

> 3) **Clients of the Observer will see fast reads, as all reads are served locally, and writes result in minimal network traffic as the number of messages required in the absence of the vote protocol is smaller** - Reads from all the other nodes will also be local only because they are in-sync with the leader, no? And I did not get the part about writes.

It's important to note that this statement from the documentation is written in the context of an important use-case for observers: multiple data center deployments with higher network latency between different data centers.  In this statement, "served locally" means served from a ZooKeeper server within the same data center as the client, so that it doesn't suffer from the longer latency of connecting to another data center.  For full context, here is a copy of the full quote:

> In fact, Observers may be used to talk to a ZooKeeper server from another data center. Clients of the Observer will see fast reads, as all reads are served locally, and writes result in minimal network traffic as the number of messages required in the absence of the vote protocol is smaller.

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you for the explanation. I have a follow-up question.
I we have the following scenario with this timeline:
- 00:00.001 absolute time, Leader receives a write
- 00:00.002 absolute time, Observer receives 1000 reads/watches
1) Does the observer starts serving even if the data is stale and when it will be aware of the new write it will forward it to the clients that are watching the node? 
2) Would the situation change if instead of an observer we had a follower? (would we maintain the ordering between write and read in the follower case?) 
Thank you!

Comment: 1) If there are other concurrent reader processes, then they can start reading immediately from the observers.  For the writer though, that process will know the "zxid" (see answer text) from the point when it completed its write, and therefore, it will never allow a stale read from an observer that has not caught up to at least that zxid.  2) No, this ZooKeeper client ordering guarantee holds true whether interacting with an Observer or a Follower on the server side.